# Node.js API Call Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'chat')

Tags: javascript, node.js, openai-api

I'm working on an excel taskpane addin that calls the Openai API, but I'm getting the "Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'chat')" error msg.

The error seems to suggest that the chat property is being called on an undefined object within thesendToGPT() function. See below for the code:

```js
const OpenAI = require("openai").default;
const openai = new OpenAI({ apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY });

async function sendToGPT(formula) {
  try {
    const completion = await openai.chat.completions.create({
      messages: [
        { role: "system", content: "You are an assistant." },
        { role: "user", content: `Explain the following excel formula ${formula}.` }],
      model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    });
    // displayGPTResponse(responseText); // Function to display the response in your application's UI
    if (completion && completion.data && completion.data.choices && completion.data.choices.length > 0) {
      const responseText = completion.data.choices[0].message.content;
      console.log(responseText);
      displayGPTResponse(responseText); // Function to display the response in your application's UI
    } else {
      console.log('No completion found.');
      displayGPTResponse('No completion found.'); // Handle no completion case
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error sending data to GPT:', error);
    displayGPTResponse(`Error: ${error.message}`); // Function to display errors in your application's UI
  }
}
```

Note that I set the API key in the environment variables and I verified that I’m on SDK v4.28

Comment: hmmm, does the same error persist if you replace require('openai').default with (require('openai')).default?

Comment: @TheBombSquad Yes it does ;(

Comment: in fact, why do you say .default? I'm reading the [npm readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openai)

Comment: What's strange is that the code syntax runs fine by itself in a separate directory. But it has issues when integrated into the taskpane.js file in the excel plugin codebase.

Comment: I mean, I opened runkit just to check out the package, openai.default really is not defined.... so does the same error occur when you just have the line as `const OpenAI = require("openai");` ?

Comment: @TheBombSquad Yes error still persists after updating